# how do i access an array by its key in java and also store the array in a hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

how do i access an array by its keys  in java

In this case i want the structure to be like this,

```
options[{"value":"0","label":"zero"},{"value":"1","label":"one"},
   {"value":"2","label":"two"}]
```

Here if i want to access `options[1].value` should give me 1 and `options[2].label` should give me two.

How can i achieve this with `Map<string><string[]>`?

Also Can i pass "options" array as one of the keys in my hash map

```
     protected Map<String, String[]> getValueProperties(int view, Field field) {
 Map<String, String> properties = new   HashMap<String,String[]>();             
        properties.put("options", []);
        return properties
    }
```

Comment: you'd like to return `List<Map<String, String>>`.

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: well basically, your `options` is a `List` of `Map`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `class` as follows

```
class Entry
{
    int value;
    string label; 
    public Entry(int val, string lbl)
    {
        this.value = val;
        this.label = lbl;
    }
}
```

Now create you `options` array as follows:

```
Entry[] options = new Entry[3];
options[0] = new Entry(0, "zero");
options[1] = new Entry(1, "one");
options[2] = new Entry(2, "two");
```

> if i want to access options[1].value should give me 1 and options[2].label should give me two

Now, options[1].value will give you 1.

Answer (score 3):

You should create a new class representing your object:

```
public final class MyObject {
    private String value;
    private String label;

    public MyObject(String label, String value) { ... }

    public String getValue() { ... }
    public String getLabel() { ... }
}
```

And then create a list of `MyObject`:

```
final List<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();
objects.add(new MyObject("zero", "0");
objects.add(new MyObject("one", "1");
objects.add(new MyObject("two", "2");
```

Then you can access the objects values directly: `objects.get(0).getValue();`

Comment: was typing something similar ;)

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without creating an object?

Comment: Can possibly be achieve the same with `List<Map<String, String>>`

Comment: @user1433211: why don't you want to define a class (objects) for this? It's the right approach.

Comment: If you don't want to create an object, you can use a Map as @Nishant proposed.

Comment: so if i create a list<map<string... for options, can i store teh "options' list in a map, if so, how would i craete the map

Comment: @nishant could you please tell me how to do it using List<Map<string?